# datastore keys query in sorted order for given keys

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a set of keys ( `Set<Key> keys`). To query the datastore for their entities, I can do `datastore.get(keys)`. How do I change my query so that the result is ordered by a certain property? say, price?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the keys, there is no point to run a new query. Get your entities (you will have a map, for example `results`) and sort them by any property like you would normally sort a collection (`results.values()`).